# How can I determine the number of bits needed for a generic integer data type in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to determine the number of bits needed for a generic integral binary data type (a nice new feature of .NET 7 -- see [IBinaryInteger<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.ibinaryinteger-1)) inside a method.  I don't want to use "sizeof" because it requires unsafe compilation.  I've come up with a solution (actually several), but have a tough time believing there's not a better answer.

Here's one solution, along with a test program:

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace BitCountApp {

    internal class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Bits in byte = " + CountBits<byte>());
            Console.WriteLine("Bits in ushort = " + CountBits<ushort>());
            Console.WriteLine("Bits in uint = " + CountBits<uint>());
            Console.WriteLine("Bits in ulong = " + CountBits<ulong>());
            Console.WriteLine("Bits in UInt128 = " + CountBits<UInt128>());
        }

        static private int CountBits<T>() where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
            return T.AllBitsSet.GetByteCount() * 8;
        }

    }

}
```

This solution works, and it's nice and compact, but it works only for data sizes that are multiples of 8.  This may be more theoretical than practical, but it would fail for a "UInt7" datatype that implemented IBinaryInteger with a 7-bit unsigned integer.

"Ah! [PopCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.popcount)!" I hear you cry.  Well, there's a problem.  If I try to implement CountBits using PopCount ...

```
static private int BitsForType<T>() where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
    return (int)(T.PopCount(T.AllBitsSet));
}
```

... I find that I cannot cast the value of PopCount, which returns a "T", to "int" (even though T is a binary integer type).

There is a solution that works correctly -- counting the number of bits for myself, like this ...

```
static private int CountBits<T>() where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
    var ones = T.AllBitsSet;
    int count = 0;
    while (ones != T.Zero) {
        count++;
        ones >>= 1;
    };
    return count;
}
```

... but, Yuk!

Is there a way to do this without counting the bits myself? I'm sort of shocked there isn't a built-in property or method for this.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that it seems odd that `PopCount` doesn't just return an `int` result. Integer types with a numbers of bits greater than what can be represented in an `int` would be impractical at best.

Comment: @500 It's particularly odd since various overloads of BitOperations.PopCount (for UIntPtr, UInt32, and UInt64) do exactly that, i.e. return an int.

Comment: You can't expect Microsoft to provide and maintain a fully complete library of all functions one can think of. They only offer commonly used ones. Apparently what you want isn't in high demand.

Comment: You're probably going to have more luck [asking this question at the dotnet repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/categories/q-a).

Comment: `Unsafe.SizeOf` and `Marshal.SizeOf` do not need unsafe compilation IIRC, did you try them?

Comment: @Ray, I hadn't tried, but I did and they work.  However, all "sizeof" solutions return byte counts, and not bit counts, and so would not work for the hypothetical UInt7 type.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no and will never be no UInt7 type. C# and .Net aren't like C which leaves a lot of details out of the spec for hypothetical computer architectures that will never exist, the smallest addresable data type is `byte`, which is defined precisely as an 8 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great answer [provided by @huoyaoyuan](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/86545#discussioncomment-5958205) on GitHub that uses the [CreateChecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createchecked?view=net-7.0) method (thanks for the suggestion @Ian):

> Use `int.CreateXXX` to cast.

So I would have:

```
static private int CountBits<T>() where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
    return int.CreateChecked(T.PopCount(T.AllBitsSet));
}
```

There are also [CreateSaturating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createsaturating?view=net-7.0) and [CreateTruncating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createtruncating?view=net-7.0) methods that behave slightly differently.